# Spring data mongo GridFsOperation.findOne doesn't find first

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb, gridfs

I'm using Spring Data Mongo version 1.10.18 with Java 8. I don't understand the behavior I am seeing with the `GridFsOperations.findOne` method.

```
Query maxAccountSetVersionQuery = new Query().addCriteria(GridFsCriteria.whereMetaData("tenantId").is(tenantId))
        .addCriteria(GridFsCriteria.whereMetaData("contextId").is(businessContextId))
        .addCriteria(GridFsCriteria.whereMetaData("collection").is("genericAuthorizationAccount"))
        .with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "metadata.accountSetVersion"));
final GridFSDBFile findOneResult = gridOperations.findOne(maxAccountSetVersionQuery);
final List<GridFSDBFile> gridFSDBFiles = gridOperations.find(maxAccountSetVersionQuery);
final GridFSDBFile firstInListResult = gridFSDBFiles.get(0);

final String output = String.format("findOneResult: %s\nfirstInListResult: %s",
                                    findOneResult.getMetaData().get("accountSetVersion"),
                                    firstInListResult.getMetaData().get("accountSetVersion"));

System.out.println(output);
```

Console output is:

```
findOneResult: 1
firstInListResult: 4
```

To be clear here the answer I am expecting is 4 which means `firstInListResult` is referencing the expected document.

So, two questions:

1. Why aren't `findOneResult` and `firstInListResult` referencing one in the same document? Or to ask it another way, Why doesn't `findOne` find the first document?
2. Is there a way to get Spring Data Mongo to find the first document in the sorted query results instead of my code having to load the entire collection into memory just to get the first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is currently a bug in Spring Data MongoDb's GridFsTemplate implementation. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2411 Surprisingly a pull request with a fix was created just 4 days ago, after I originally asked this question.